# Can NSIS Create an exe File While Running on Linux Machine?

Tags: installation, executable, nsis

We moved our **"TeamCity"** server to Linux,
and installed nsis on it.
my question is,
can nsis create an exe file while running on a linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS only supports Windows. But, from appendix G.3, NSIS provide the following information:

> G.3 Building on POSIX
>
> As of NSIS 2.01, the compiler, makensis, also compiles on POSIX platforms. POSIX platforms include Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X and others. Since the generated installer will eventually run on Windows, a cross-compiler is needed in order to compile them.
>
> If no cross-compiler is available, use the following:

```
scons SKIPSTUBS=all SKIPPLUGINS=all SKIPUTILS=all SKIPMISC=all
      NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA_PATH=no PREFIX=/path/to/extracted/zip
      install-compiler

scons NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA_PATH=no PREFIX=/path/to/extracted/zip
      /path/to/extracted/zip/LibraryLocal
```

> This should only build makensis and install it to the directory where a pre-compiled package, such as the nightly build or a zipped release version (nsis-x.xx.zip), is extracted. Note that the in order for this to work, the precompiled package must be compiled using the exact same sources as makensis. In particular, Source\exehead\config.h, the options passed to scons and Source\exehead\fileform.h must be identical. Nightly builds and zipped release versions are built with the default options.
>
> To build a native version of NSIS Menu, install wxWidgets 2.8 and build as usual. wx-config must be in the path.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you use Ansible, you may try the following role to automate makensis build on Linux platform: https://galaxy.ansible.com/inponomarev/nsis/